# Find $a^3 + b^3 +c^3, $ given $a+b+c=12$ and $a^3 \cdot b^4 \cdot c^5 = 0.1 \cdot (600)^3$

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$a+b+c=12$  and  $a^3 \cdot b^4 \cdot c^5 = 0.1 \cdot (600)^3$.
Find  $a^3 + b^3 +c^3 = ?$

My approach is to use AM-GM inequality. Is it correct?

Comment: Instead of the lengthy title which adds nothing to the post, you should have presented your ideas in detail. Also, are there any conditions on the numbers? Positive? Integer? Rational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers have to be positive, then the problem can be solved using AM-GM, indeed.

Namely, consider the following 12 numbers:

$\frac{a}{3}, \frac{a}{3}, \frac{a}{3}, \frac{b}{4}, \frac{b}{4}, \frac{b}{4}, \frac{b}{4}, \frac{c}{5}, \frac{c}{5}, \frac{c}{5}, \frac{c}{5}, \frac{c}{5}$.

The AM is $1$, as $a+b+c=12$.

Thus, the GM is at most $1$, so the product of these $12$ numbers is at most $1$, which yields 
$\frac{a^3b^4c^5}{3^3\cdot 4^4\cdot 5^5}\leq 1$. 
As $a^3b^4c^5 = 0.1\cdot 600^3 = 3^3\cdot 4^4\cdot 5^5$, the above inequality is sharp: it holds with equality. 
Thus the AM and the GM of the given $12$ numbers coincide, which means that all $12$ numbers must be equal. 
Hence, $\frac{a}{3}= \frac{b}{4}= \frac{c}{5}$. 
Using $a+b+c=12$ we obtain $a=3, b=4, c=5$. 
Now you just have to sustitute this into $a^3+b^3+c^3$, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you I got it:)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you are happy with the answer, you should accept it.